# Friend operators for template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, friend-function

I have a template class, to which I declared 2 `operator+` methods. Their declaration is:

1) `const MyClass<T> operator+ (int num) const;`

and

2) `friend const MyClass<T> operator+ <>(int  num, const MyClass<T>& other);`

Following [this FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends), the .hpp file looks something like this:

```
//forward declaration of the class.
template<class T>
class MyClass;

//forward declaration of the operator+
template<class T>
const MyClass<T> operator+ (int num, const MyClass<T>& other);

template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    ...
    const MyClass<T> operator+ (int num) const;
    friend const MyClass<T> operator+ <>(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);
    ...
};
```

(And later I have the definitions of those methods).

Note that the 2 `operator+` methods are used in different situations:

The first in

```
MyClass mc;
mc+5;
```

And the second in

```
MyClass mc;
5+mc;
```

But for some reason, when I compile it in g++ (version 4.8.2, if that matters), I get the error:

```
declaration of ‘operator+’ as non-function
   friend const MyClass<T> operator+ <>(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);
```

Note that the error refers to the `friend` `operator+` method

But, if I remove the declaration of the first `operator+` method (i.e. leaving only the `friend` one), then everything compiles just fine!

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why, but switching the order makes it compile (will try to find an explaination):

```
//forward declaration of the class.
template<class T>
class MyClass;

//forward declaration of the operator+
template<class T>
const MyClass<T> operator+(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);

template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
  friend const MyClass<T> operator+<>(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);
  const MyClass<T> operator+ (int num) const;

};
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Maksim for pointing out that my doubts were true. What happens is that the names of both operators clash and thus the error. Normally the second operator would have the class name in it's name, but since in the class declaration you are inside class scope the names clash. If the non class member operator would be in a different namespace, e.g:

```
//forward declaration of the class.
template<class T>
class MyClass;

//forward declaration of the operator+
namespace Foo
{
template<class T>
const MyClass<T> operator+(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);
}
template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
  const MyClass<T> operator+ (int num) const;
  friend const MyClass<T> Foo::operator+<>(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);

};

using namespace Foo;

int main()
{
  MyClass<int> a;
  5 + a;
}
```

it would be fine since the names would be distinct. Also if you would use them as friends on another object it would also be fine:

```
//forward declaration of the class.
template<class T>
class MyClass;

//forward declaration of the operator+
template<class T>
const MyClass<T> operator+(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);

template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
  const MyClass<T> operator+ (int num) const;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
friend const MyClass<T> operator+<>(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);
friend const MyClass<T> MyClass<T>::operator+(int num);
};

int main()
{
  MyClass<int> a;
  5 + a;
}
```

I hope this explains these examples explain the cause.

Comment: That's probably because of the name clashes: if you put friend operator into, say, `namespace A` and say `friend const MyClass<T> A::operator+<>(int num, const MyClass<T>& other);` it will compile in any order

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov I was thinking about that, but then I though that the instance operator should be prefixed with class name, however if the names  are compared in class scope this is not needed, correct?

Comment: I think that non-templated instance operators would probably be prefixed; however, since these are templates, no code is yet generated for them, and this might lead to compiler getting confused... Type is part of a name decoration, so this definitely can't happen before the template is being instantiated

Comment: `operator+` should really, really be in the same namespace as `MyClass`, otherwise you block ADL.  Still, the example is illuminating!

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Thank you, this solution works well. But as with your second solution, the '5+a' statement calls the operator+ method we forward declaration'd, but in order for that method to access private members of MyClass, we need to add its declaration to the MyClass's declaration (as a friend), and we're back to square one.

Comment: @Mikrosaft sorry i did not follow - what did you mean with "second solution"? If you meant the last example with the third class then I understood, and yeah in that example you would get the initial issue, I just wanted to point out that outside class scope the method will be prefixed and thus a name clash will not occur.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, this is what you actually want:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass operator+ (int num) const;
  friend MyClass operator+(int num, const MyClass& other) {
    return other+num;
  }
};
```

I made a number of changes, all on purpose.

I removed the forward declaration of `MyClass<T>` and `operator+`, because neither are needed.

I made the non-member `operator+` an inline friend, and no longer a template.  This is what I call a Koenig operator: it can only be accessed via ADL (argument dependent lookup) on `MyClass`.  It is not a template: however one independent non-template function is created for each template class.

As this function is almost certainly just going to mindlessly forward its arguments to the member `operator+`, I did it inline right there.

Finally, I removed `const` from the return type.  `const` in return types does little except block some move optimizations.

The end result is code that is shorter, simpler and easier to work with.

I often go a step further when I want an industrial quality solution:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass& operator+=(int num); // do actual work here
  template<class Self>
  friend MyClass operator+(int num, Self&& self) {
    auto tmp = std::forward<Self>(self); // perfect forwarding
    tmp += num; // delegate to +=
    return tmp; // elide return value
  }
  template<class Self>
  friend MyClass operator+(Self&& self, int num) {
    return num + std::forward<Self>(self); // DRY principle
  }
};
```

where I forward everything through to member `+=`.  The above version also enables perfect forwarding of `MyClass` into `+`.  While the operator looks overly greedy (I mean, it doesn't seem to restrict `Self` to be of type `MyClass` at all!), because it can only be found via ADL on `MyClass<T>`, `self` *must* be a reference to an instance of `MyClass`!

clang interestingly requires a `template<class Self, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<std::decay_t<Self>>{}>* = nullptr>` for the `operator+`s due to it treating some restrictions on operator+ as hard errors, instead of SFINAE errors.

This strategy, basing other operators off `+=` style operators, and using Koenig operators for `+` style operators that just forward to `+=`, works well in a wide variety of situations.

You can even use inheritance to strip out the boilerplate to convert `+=` into `+`.  This doesn't even require CRTP.

```
struct plus_impl {
  template<class Self,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<std::decay_t<Self>>{}>* = nullptr
  >
  friend std::decay_t<Self> operator+(int num, Self&& self) {
    auto tmp = std::forward<Self>(self); // perfect forward a copy
    tmp += num; // delegate to +=
    return tmp; // elide return value
  }
  template<class Self,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<std::decay_t<Self>>{}>* = nullptr
  >
  friend std::decay_t<Self> operator+(Self&& self, int num) {
    return num + std::forward<Self>(self); // DRY principle
  }
};

template<class T>
class MyClass : public plus_impl {
public:
  MyClass& operator+=(int num){
      std::cout << "+=" << num << "\n";
      return *this;
  }
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79b5fe36a20c7c23).

We use the magic of ADL here.  Inheriting from `plus_impl` means that `MyClass<T> + int` finds the `operator+` in `plus_impl`.  As `operator+` is a template operator, it actually gets the `MyClass<T>` as a `MyClass<T>`, not as a `plus_impl`.  The implementation of `operator+` then uses `MyClass<T>`'s `+=` to do the work.

I believe this technique is similar to how `boost::operators` work, except it uses CRTP (I remember some discussion about them using it because some older compilers didn't do the right thing without it?)

Another fun thing about this technique is that subclasses of `MyClass<T>` [magically get `+` support](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26d584b92193faac).

Comment: Thank you for this, very interresting and enlightening:)

Comment: `boost::operators` requires you to provide the type still. So it'd be `template <typename T> class MyClass : public boost::addable<MyClass<T>>`. So not anywhere near as cool.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should look like this:

```
//forward declaration of the class.
template<class T>
class MyClass;

//forward declaration of the operator+
template<class T>
MyClass<T> operator+ (int num, const MyClass<T>& other);

template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass<T> operator+ (int num) const;
    template<typename P> friend  MyClass<P> operator+ (int num, const MyClass<P>& other);
};
```

Returning `const MyClass<T>` make no sence because const is discarded anyway.

Comment: But he wants to allow only instances of the operator+ with `T` being the same type as `MyClass` template parameter `T` to be friends. With this for example if there is a `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<float>`  the `operator+` for `float`  it will be able to access `MyClass<int>`. Example: http://goo.gl/LAQaxz

Comment: @rudolfs and why do you care about that difference?

Comment: @Yakk maybe I'm wrong, but IMHO if OP wanted to allow all specializations of the operator to be friends he would have done so.

Comment: Like @RudolfsBundulis said, I don't want this behavior to happen.